# How do I use static method on a Type parameter?

Tags: typescript, types, static

I have two types, Point and Line, both containing the `.fromHash()` static method. I want to call it for each type differently because the classes both have a different definition of `.fromHash()` method.

```js
class Point {
    static fromHash() {
        // logic one
    }
}

class Line {
    static fromHash() {
        // logic two
    }
}


const filterIdentical = <Type extends Point & Line>(array: Type[]): Type[] => {
    // Do some calculations

    // THIS IS THE CODE I NEED HELP WITH
    // return Type.fromHash(array) <- Something like this?
}
```

Comment: `fromHash()` doesn't take any inputs but you want to call it with an input?  Why are you writing `Point & Line`? Do you mean `Point | Line`?  These are typos or something and it would be very helpful if you wrote a [mcve] we could test.  My main question here is: since the code that actually runs will be JavaScript (TypeScript just compiles to JavaScript), how would you propose implementing `filterIdentical` in JavaScript without types?  How do you want the array of instances to access their static properties? Show that in code and someone can probably help.

Comment: I can imagine an answer like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/N9J7Vm) but only if you are passing in the constructor as well as the array.  If you don't do that, then you need to do unsafe things like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMRPlW) and it's not anything I'd recommend.

Comment: The second one is the stuff i wanted thank u so much! I forgot to include parameters for fromHash in the definition because i'm stupid lol

Comment: Hmm, so I can write up the second one as an answer but it's not type safe, unfortunately.  TypeScript's type system is structural, so an object without the right `constructor` can still be assignable to `Point` or `Line` and then you'll get runtime errors without compiler errors, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8AddN).  Why do you even want a `static` method if you need an instance of the class to call it?  Just make it a regular method like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlpKGN).